# Cool language nerds won't hang out with me

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story, language

> It has long been my dream to be a part of the extremely exclusive **Language Nerds' Club**. Today, I walked into their clubhouse and stated my wish to become a *bona fide* member. See how I used Latin there? That should qualify me immediately, right? As it turns out, it's not that simple.
>
> The guy at the door gave me a piece of paper and said: "To get in, you have to say the passphrase. And say it loud! I want everyone to hear it."
>
> I'm stumped now. How do I fulfill my dream and get into this exciting club?
>
> [image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get in the club, proudly pronounce:

> **I AM A BIG GEEK, SIR!**

---

Character, transliteration, and script table *(look at how beautifully monospaced it is)*:

> ```
> character(s) | translit | script     | geek notes
> -------------|----------|------------|------------
>            த | TA      | TAMIL      |
>            के | KE      | DEVANAGARI |
>            ਫ਼ੋ | FO      | GURMUKHI   |
>           ‎އުރް‎ | UR      | THAANA     |
>            ث | TH      | ARABIC     |
>           เละ | LE      | THAI       |
>           ট্টে | TTE     | BENGALI    |
>           로 | RO      | HANGUL     | 
>            ֆ | F       | ARMENIAN   |
>           σκ | SK      | GREEK      |
>            ᕆ | RI      | INUKTITUT  | properly Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics, since ᕆ is used in other languages (e.g. some dialects of Eastern Cree)
>           پت | PT      | PERSIAN    | properly Arabic script, since پ is used in other languages (e.g. Urdu)
>           на | NA      | CYRILLIC   |
>            מֶ‬ | ME      | HEBREW     |
> ```

The transliteration clues the next step:

> **TAKE FOURTH LETTER OF SCRIPT NAME**

which gives us our passcode,

> **I AM A BIG GEEK, SIR!**, which indeed one must be to join the Language Nerds' Club.

*p.s. I think this puzzle is exemplary for the `#enigmatic-puzzle` tag. Please add that tag and thank you for a brilliant puzzle.*

Comment: Tag added. Nice job!

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

> Taking it as face value, I presume you have to get the phonetic pronounciations of all the characters in the letter. Which are from different languages. Here's what I've surmised so far. I can't figure any rhyme or reason to the languages chosen, though. And I'm sufficiently troubled by the fact that some languages are read forward and some backwards. Must be missing something...

> ? ? ? ? se(arabic)

> ? n(thai) ? ? t + o (korean) fe(armenian)

> ? ? ta (arabic?) na(russian) ?

Comment: 로 is _ro_ in Korean, not _to_.

Answer (score 1):

on line one this is what I interpreted it as so far:

Line 1, Character 1:

> ?

Line 1, Character 2:

> के  ke

Line 1, Character 3:

> ढ़ॆ dhai

Line 1, Character 4:

> ?

Line 1, Character 5:

> ث   th